# Append IMG Objects into Table cells

Tags: javascript, image, object

I have a task i need to complete for an assignment.

I have to create a table with Javascript. Which i have no problem doing this.

I then have to use Javascript to preload twenty image slices into an array. Which I can also do.

This is where I'm stuck. I have to take the preloaded images and append them into the the into the table cells in order.

Its driving me insane I cant find any instruction on how to do this. Can anyone help?

R

Aaron

**EDIT**

I have added my current example of the js code

```
//create a table
function imageTable(){
   var table = '';
   var rows = 4;
  var cols = 5;
  var queryString = window.location.search;
    queryString = queryString.substring(1);
  var result = queryString;
  if (result === "bcpot002"){
  for(var r = 0; r < rows;r++)
  {
    table += '<tr class="myTr">';
    for(var c = 0; c < cols;c++)
    {
        table += '<td class="myTd">'+ 'test' + '</td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
  }

  document.getElementById("ImageContent").innerHTML = '<table class="myTable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" align="center">' + table + '</table>';
  }
}
window.onload = imageTable;


//Preload images script
var myTable = document.getElementById("mytable");
var myimages=[];
function preloadimagesRedBowl()
{
    for (i=0;i<preloadimagesRedBowl.arguments.length;i++)
    {
        myimages[i]=new Image();
        myimages[i].src=preloadimagesRedBowl.arguments[i];
        myimages[i].className="myImg";
  }
            {
         var td = document.getElementsByClassName("myTd");
                        for (i=0;i<td.length;i++)
                        {
                        td.appendChild(myimages);
                        }

    }
}


//Images to be preloaded.
preloadimagesRedBowl("../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c1.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c2.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c4.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c5.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot006_r1_c1.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot006_r1_c2.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot006_r1_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot006_r1_c4.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot006_r1_c5.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot008_r1_c1.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot008_r1_c2.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot008_r1_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot008_r1_c4.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot008_r1_c5.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot010_r1_c1.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot010_r1_c2.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot010_r1_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot010_r1_c4.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot010_r1_c5.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot013_r1_c1.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot013_r1_c2.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot013_r1_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot013_r1_c4.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot013_r1_c5.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot020_r1_c1.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot020_r1_c2.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot020_r1_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot020_r1_c4.jpg", "../../images/Large/bcpot020_r1_c5.jpg");
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Give this a quick read and edit your question: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Provide some code you have tried. Maybe attach a link to a repl.it or jsfiddle example.

Comment: However, [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) is likely the droid you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks I have added the code that I'm working with. am I on the right path? Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'td' element for your table and appendChild your images to it.

```
var newTd = document.createElement("td");
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.setAttribute("src", image_location);
img.setAttribute("width", "150");
img.setAttribute("height", "150");
newTd.appendChild(img);
document.getElementById("yourTableId").appendChild(newTd);
```

Do it in a for loop (image_location will hold the next image location in every loop).

Comment: Thanks I have added the code that I'm working with. am I on the right path? Does this help?

Comment: I am sorry i didn't understand what are you referring with your question.